# name the label dynamically -ios

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, text

I have created lables dynamically in my storyboard.
now i want to name those lables.
i am having no idea what should i do.
this is my code:

```
<label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Data Updated on  July 7, 2012" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" minimumFontSize="10" id="ovU-eL-SMN">
                               <rect key="frame" x="313" y="961" width="444" height="30"/>
                               <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinX="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                               <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="16"/>
                               <color key="textColor" red="0.047058823530000002" green="0.0" blue="0.35294117650000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                               <color key="highlightedColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                           </label>
```

here, i am using html code in storyboard.i am fetching value from database and put those values as lable text.I just have to name it and the value has to be passed in appdelegate
this is the mainstoryboard file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set tag property of each label like 10 , 11 , 12 as many you have label.

Then

```
for(int i=10 ;i<last_label_Tag;i++)
{
UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
lbl.text=@"Define text for the labels"// or you can use separate Labels without loop.
}
```